# Is it possible for a Chrome extension to access an IndexedDB database created by a specific domain?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, indexeddb

If http://example.com/ creates an IndexedDB database, is it possible for a Chrome extension (used on domains other than `example.com`) to open and query this database?

Comment: this discussion says that we can use indexdb in chrome extension
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38905362/update-object-stored-in-chrome-extensions-local-storage

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, you can not do it. The data storage is sandboxed http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/offline/storage/

Comment: Being sandboxed wouldn't necessarily exclude allowing access, as Chrome extensions can make cross-domain HTTP requests when permission has been granted. In this case, though, there just doesn't seem to be a way to even ask for access to an IndexedDB from a specific domain.

Comment: Alf, add a bug at crbug.com describing your use case. Things like this have been discussed.

Comment: Important point: a _content script_ can access it as long as a page at `example.com` is open.

Comment: I'm also want to know the answer to this question and I'm a little be confused as I came across this: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/instant-and-offline/web-storage/indexeddb-best-practices. Where it says: "Unlike server-side databases where you can restrict unauthorized access, client-side databases are accessible to browser extensions and developer tools, and they can be cleared by the user."

Answer (score 5):

Yes, IndexedDB can be accessed through chrome extension with the help of content scripts. Content Scripts can access the indexedDB storage of the domain you have specified in manifest.json file.

For more info check here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60002682/9131807

Comment: But I believe data isn't shared as each indexdb store is scoped via origin? If your requiring sharing of data i believe only storing the indexdb data in background script is the way to go.

Comment: @The.Wolfgang.Grimmer with MV3 it's not a clear decision anymore, since the background script is not an option