# Update object stored in chrome extension's local storage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, local-storage, google-chrome-app

I'm developing a chrome extension and I will store objects sent by server.
For example, I will receive:

> command = {id:"1", type: "A", size: "B", priority: "C"}

If I had a database, I would insert it as a line in table `commands`.
Using chrome.storage, I'm storing an array of these object in key `commands`.

But, when I receive a new command by server, I have to **get** from local storage, update the array and then **set** again. I'm worried about cases when I receive another command while I'm getting and setting or while I delete a stored command. I'm thinking about semaphores, but I don't know if it's a great idea.

Can someone suggest me what to do?

thanks!

Comment: How about making sure all previous changes are completed before starting a new one by chaining promises?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extensions can use a database: [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Using_IndexedDB) (the sample code may look convoluted, but it's pretty simple in the actual extensions, for example two small functions [here](https://github.com/stylish-userstyles/stylish-chrome/blob/master/src/storage.js), getStyles and saveStyle, or [IDB-keyval wrapper library](https://github.com/jakearchibald/idb-keyval/blob/master/idb-keyval.js)).

If you want to use `chrome.storage`, just maintain a global `queue` array

```
const queue = [];
```

that is populated by the server listener:

```
queue.push(newItem);
updateStorage();
```

The updateStorage may be a global function too:

```
function updateStorage() {
    if (!queue.length || updateStorage.running) {
        return;
    }
    updateStorage.running = true;
    chrome.storage.local.get('commands', data => {
        data.commands = [].concat(data.commands || [], queue);
        queue = [];
        chrome.storage.local.set(data, () => {
          updateStorage.running = false;
          if (queue.length) updateStorage();
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: can we use a global queue array with chrome.storage in a manifest v3 extension, which operates in the context of an ephemeral service worker? Can we assume the service worker won't exit until the queue is processed?

Comment: After https://crbug.com/1371876 is fixed the SW will live for 30 seconds since the last [properly registered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74516519) `chrome` event or a wake-up due to usage of a standard ServiceWorker API from another extension page. Currently there's no such guarantee, so you'll have to [make the SW "persistent"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66618269).