# In a Chrome extension, how to ensure previous promise resolves before the next one using chrome-promise?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, concurrency, promise

I've been using the [chrome-promise](https://github.com/tfoxy/chrome-promise) library to wrap the Chrome extension API with a facade that returns promises instead of using callbacks.  This has generally worked quite well, but I seem to be running into an issue with `chrome.storage.local` APIs.

My extension's event page listens for the `chrome.tabs.onActivated` and `chrome.tabs.onRemoved` events.  When it gets the `onActivated` event, it adds the tab info to an array and calls `chrome.storage.local.set(data)` to store the updated array in local storage.

When it gets the `onRemoved` event, it calls `chromepromise.storage.local.get(null).then(...)` to get the list of tabs via a promise, removes the tab info from the array, and then calls `chrome.storage.local.set()` again to save the updated array.

The issue is that the `onActivated` event seems to trigger before the promise flow from the `onRemoved` event resolves.  So the `onActivated` handler retrieves the old stored array, with the closed tab still in it, and then pushes the newly activated tab.  So the stored tab data now includes a tab that's already been closed.

I'm assuming this is an issue with using promises instead of callbacks, but I'm wondering if anyone else has run into this problem with this library and worked around it.

#### Update

As wOxxOm [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47193925/in-a-chrome-extension-how-to-ensure-previous-promise-resolves-before-the-next-o#comment81362691_47193925), this is a generic problem with "arbitrating unpredictable asynchronous access to a single resource such as `chrome.storage`" and not unique to the `chrome-promise` library.

After researching a bit, I came up with a couple solutions, added as answers below.  One uses a mutex to ensure (I think) that one promise chain's getting and setting data in `chrome.storage` completes before the next one starts.  The other queues the whole promise chain that's created from an event and doesn't start the next one until the current one has fully completed.  I'm not sure which is better, though I suppose locking for a shorter period of time is better.

Any suggestions or better answers are welcome.

Comment: is `chrome.storage.local.set()` inside the .then of `chromepromise.storage.local.get(null).then(...)` ?

Comment: You need to implement your own mutex-based controller for chrome.storage or use a queue ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38906083)) and debounce.

Comment: My concern is that I'm not sure there's a way to do that without having a persistent background page in the extension. Event pages can get flushed when they stop running, so I'm persisting state to `chrome.storage.local`. But if the promise chains for setting that and then getting that can happen in different orders, I don't see how to persist a queue that would ensure order via that process either.

Comment: Queuing or using a mutex is a standard mechanism of arbitrating unpredictable asynchronous access to a single resource such as chrome.storage. Event page is unloaded after 5 seconds of inactivity so it shouldn't affect this case.

Comment: @w0xx0m, I looked at the queue example but I wasn't sure how it would apply here.  I added to the question a simplified version of the approach I tried, but which isn't working.  Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Mutex

**Update:** I ended up using the approach below to create a [module](https://github.com/fwextensions/QuicKey/blob/master/src/js/background/storage.js) that uses a mutex to ensure gets and sets of the Chrome extension storage maintain their order.  It seems to be working well so far.

---

This solution uses the mutex implementation from [this article](https://blog.jcoglan.com/2016/07/12/mutexes-and-javascript/).  `addTab()` and `removeTab()` call `storageMutex.synchronize()` with a function that does all the storage getting and setting.  This should prevent later events from affecting the storage of earlier events.

The code below is a very simplified version of the extension, but it does run.  The `playNextEvent()` calls at the bottom simulate opening 4 tabs, switching back to tab 2 and closing it, which then causes tab 3 to activate.  `setTimeout()`s are used so that everything doesn't run as one long call stack.

```js
function Mutex() {
    this._busy  = false;
    this._queue = [];
}

Object.assign(Mutex.prototype, {
    synchronize: function(task) {
        var self = this;

        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            self._queue.push([task, resolve, reject]);
            if (!self._busy) {
                self._dequeue();
            }
        });
    },

    _dequeue: function() {
        var next = this._queue.shift();

        if (next) {
            this._busy = true;
            this._execute(next);
        } else {
            this._busy = false;
        }
    },

    _execute: function(record) {
        var task = record[0],
            resolve = record[1],
            reject = record[2],
            self = this;

        task().then(resolve, reject).then(function() {
            self._dequeue();
        });
    }
});


const storageMutex = new Mutex();


function onActivated(tabID) {
    console.log("EVENT onActivated", tabID);
    return Promise.resolve(tabID).then(tab => addTab(tab));
}

function onRemoved(tabID) {
    console.log("EVENT onRemoved", tabID);
    return removeTab(tabID);
}


var localData = {
        tabs: []
    };

function delay(time) {
   return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, time));
}

function getData()
{
    return delay(0).then(() => JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(localData)));
}

function saveData(data, source)
{
    return delay(0)
        .then(() => {
            localData = data;
            console.log("save from:", source, "localData:", localData);
            return Promise.resolve(localData);
        });
}

function addTab(tabID)
{
    return storageMutex.synchronize(() => getData().then((data) => {
        console.log("addTab", tabID, "data:", data);
        data.tabs = data.tabs.filter(tab => tab != tabID);
        data.tabs.push(tabID);
        return saveData(data, "addTab");
    }));
}

function removeTab(tabID)
{
    return storageMutex.synchronize(() => getData().then((data) => {
        console.log("removeTab", tabID, "data:", data);
        data.tabs = data.tabs.filter(tab => tab != tabID);
        return saveData(data, "removeTab");
    }));
}


const events = [
    () => onActivated(1),
    () => onActivated(2),
    () => onActivated(3),
    () => onActivated(4),
    () => onActivated(2),
    () => { onRemoved(2); onActivated(3) }
];

function playNextEvent()
{
    var event = events.shift();

    if (event) {
        delay(0).then(() => { event(); delay(0).then(playNextEvent) });
    }
}

playNextEvent();
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Queue

This solution uses a very simple queuing mechanism.  The event handlers call `queue()` with a function that kicks off the promise chain to handle that event.  If there isn't already a promise in the queue, then the function is called immediately.  Otherwise, it's pushed on the queue and will be triggered when the current promise chain finishes.  This means only one event can be processed at a time, which might not be as efficient.

```js
var taskQueue = [];

function queue(
    fn)
{
    taskQueue.push(fn);
    processQueue();
}

function processQueue()
{
    const nextTask = taskQueue[0];

    if (nextTask && !(nextTask instanceof Promise)) {
        taskQueue[0] = nextTask()
            .then((result) => {
                console.log("RESULT", result);
                taskQueue.shift();
                processQueue();
        });
    }
}


function onActivated(tabID) {
    console.log("EVENT onActivated", tabID);
    queue(() => Promise.resolve(tabID).then(tab => addTab(tab)));
}

function onRemoved(tabID) {
    console.log("EVENT onRemoved", tabID);
    queue(() => removeTab(tabID));
}


var localData = {
        tabs: []
    };

function delay(time) {
   return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, time));
}

function getData()
{
    return delay(0).then(() => JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(localData)));
}

function saveData(data, source)
{
    return delay(0)
        .then(() => {
            localData = data;
            console.log("save from:", source, "localData:", localData);
            return Promise.resolve(localData);
        });
}

function addTab(tabID)
{
    return getData().then((data) => {
        console.log("addTab", tabID, "data:", data);
        data.tabs = data.tabs.filter(tab => tab != tabID);
        data.tabs.push(tabID);
        return saveData(data, "addTab");
    });
}

function removeTab(tabID)
{
    return getData().then((data) => {
        console.log("removeTab", tabID, "data:", data);
        data.tabs = data.tabs.filter(tab => tab != tabID);
        return saveData(data, "removeTab");
    });
}


const events = [
    () => onActivated(1),
    () => onActivated(2),
    () => onActivated(3),
    () => onActivated(4),
    () => onActivated(2),
    () => { onRemoved(2); onActivated(3) }
];

function playNextEvent()
{
    var event = events.shift();

    if (event) {
        delay(0).then(() => { event(); delay(0).then(playNextEvent) });
    }
}

playNextEvent();
```