# Why my chrome.storage.session object is not ever updated?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, google-chrome-extension

I need some help to improve my scraper chrome extension.
I try to summarize what the extension does:

1. clickin' a button in popup.html it opens 10 tabs:

popup.js

```
scrapeRiassunto.addEventListener("click", async () => {

await chrome.storage.session.clear();
let [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query({active:true, currentWindow: true});

chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: {tabId: tab.id},
    func: getAllMatches,
    args:[0,from_partita,to_partita,"riassunto"]
});
});
```

2. in my background there is the listener chrome.tabs.onUpdated that scrapes data in the tabs (when status == complete) and then updates the storage.session in this way:

background.js

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
//alert(tab.id + info.url + info.status );
var exUrl = ''
if (changeInfo.status === 'complete' && tab.url.search(/<link>/i) != -1) {
    exUrl = tab.url;
    console.log("executing scraping script");
    chrome.scripting.executeScript({
        target: {tabId: tab.id},
        func: scrapeRiassuntoFromPage,
        // // //func: getAllMatches,
    });
}
```

function scrapeRiassuntoFromPage (defined in background.js)

```
//scraping data from tab... and update storage  
chrome.storage.session.get(function(cfg) {
        if(typeof(cfg["riassunti"]) !== 'undefined' && cfg["riassunti"] instanceof Array) { 
            cfg["riassunti"].push(riassuntoEvento);
        } else {
            cfg["riassunti"] = [riassuntoEvento];
        }
        chrome.storage.session.set(cfg); 
    }); chrome.runtime.sendMessage({riassuntoEvento, from: "scrapeRiassuntoFromPage"});
```

finally, clicking another button in popup.html, I access to the chrome.storage.session object to retrieve stored data and create a CSV with simple code:

```
exportBtn.addEventListener("click", async () => {
if(document.getElementById("linkCSV")){
    document.getElementById("linkCSV").remove();
}

const scrapedData = await chrome.storage.session.get();
//alert(Object.values(scrapedData));
console.log(scrapedData); ...
```

Everything works fine BUT not ever!. Sometimes I miss some data of some tab and I cannot understand why. Do you have any tips?
Thanks

Comment: This code is not sufficient to diagnose the problem exacty since we don't see the timing when it runs in relation to the rest. It might be the standard problem of asynchronous storage updates, see [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38906083).

Comment: I didn't really understand how to set the global queue array in my background.js in your suggested solution.

Comment: Add `const queue = [];` at the start of the script and then do what's shown in the example i.e. queue.push(newItem); updateStorage();

Comment: I tried to initialize queue at the beginning of bg.js but I ever get queue not defined. Anyway I suppose Sw “dies” before it finishes the operation in some tab (maybe too much time for loading the page)

Comment: If done correctly as shownin the example, `queue` cannot be undefined because it's used within the same file within the same running session. Do you load the background script or its dependencies somewhere else e.g. in the popup? If not, I think you'll have to show the complete relevant code so we can see the timing and relation of the parts, otherwise we're stuck.

Comment: just added more details. thanks for your time wOxxOm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by accessing the asynchronous chrome.storage in the injected code (function) because it runs in the tab, which is a separate process, and there are many such tabs. When one tab writes the storage this new data isn't yet propagated to all the other tabs, which pushed their own values into the old data and then wrote to the storage thus overwriting data of the first tab.

The solution is to maintain a single source of truth in the background script, which will be the only one to read/write the storage.

Warning! It can't be inside the function or file specified in executeScript as those run in the tab in the same environment as a content script specified in manifest.json.

Let's combine [updating array in chrome.storage](/a/38906083) with [maintaining global variables in MV3](/a/73090402):

```js
// background.js
let results;
// restoring variables when the background script restarts after dying due to inactivity
let busy = chrome.storage.session.get().then(data => {
  results = data.results || [];
  busy = null;
});

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(async (tabId, info, tab) => {
  const {url} = tab;
  if (info.status === 'complete' && /<link>/i.test(url)) {
    const [{result}] = await chrome.scripting.executeScript({
      target: {tabId},
      func: scrape,
    });
    if (busy) await busy;
    results.push(...result);
    chrome.storage.session.set({results});
  }
});

async function scrape() {
  let foo = document.querySelector('#foo')?.textContent;
  let bar = document.querySelector('#bar')?.textContent;
  // ...............
  return [
    foo,
    bar,
  ];
}
```

In your UI (the popup) you can use [chrome.storage.session.onChanged](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/api/storage#event-StorageArea-onChanged) event to display the updates dynamically.

Comment: thank you very much for the explanation!! I will try asap and i wll back with a feeback

Comment: I updated the whole rxtension following your example and it works as expected!!! thank you very much! I will stress it with more tests but till now i didnt lost any data also opening 20 tabs.